# Anything similar to Duolingo for learning Tagalog?

Tags: resource-request, online-learning, electronic-resources, tagalog

I think the way Duolingo executes language learning is great. It's a really fun way to understand the basics/vocabulary and the gamification keeps you interested. Unfortunately, as most users have noticed, Duolingo does not have all languages.

So far, I've only found flash card type apps. The best alternative I found was [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/).

Are there any other Duolingo-type apps out there? When I mean by similar, I mean similar in the way Duolingo separates its categories and have them build on each other. Of course, there should be some gamification aspects as well.

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning!

Comment: Thanks @fi12! Glad to be here.

Comment: Which specific characteristics of Duolingo are you looking for in this app?  Gamification specifically? Or something else?

Comment: I like the separation of categories they have and they way they build upon each other (Basics, Phrases, etc.). I also really like the combination of exercises they do, specifically the translations back to your primary language and the speaking exercises. Gamification just keeps it interesting and more engaged than flash cards, you know?

Comment: Mondly recently released Tagalog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of the basic Tagalog learning resources I know of that you can try for free in addition to Memrise and Duolingo are the following:

1. [Beginner Tagalog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.beginnertagalog) app for Android.
2. [StartFromZero_Tagalog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shex.startfromzero_tagalog) app for Android.

Comment: Thank you! I will pass these along to my husband. :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe a Tagalog learning mobile app that has audio recorded by native speakers will help you a lot. I hope this app may help you learn Tagalog : [Learn Dalubhasa's Easy Tagalog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dalubhasareviewcenter.easytagalog) . This app will teach you from different ways of counting in Tagalog, telling time, travel and dining phrases to advanced Tagalog. This app consists of Tagalog words and sentence structures and offline dictionary with example of sentences. It also has detailed explanation even on using affixes, verbs, adjectives, slang, Taglish, and idiomatic expressions.
Being a native Tagalog speaker, I must say that the easiest part could be nouns and adjectives. Verbs, idiomatic expressions, and active and passive voices are the most difficult. Well, it really depends on how people learn.

Cheers!!! ;-)

Comment: Ooh. Salamat! I'll pass this on to my husband.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [learningtagalog.com](http://learningtagalog.com/index.html) as it literally is based on helping you learn Tagalog. It seems to be for free and has great reviews. It claims to be quite fun and quick, similar to Duolingo's gamification techniques. With all the reviews, it seems to be a highly proclaimed product with lots of happy customers. Its [lesson plan](http://learningtagalog.com/course/index.html#how_it_works) also seems pretty similar to Duolingo, allowing each lesson to build up on each other, starting from the basics to the more advanced terms.

[Your example (Memrise)](http://www.memrise.com/about/) is also a good choice. Though based on flash cards as well, its lesson plans are similar to Duolingo with its gamification techniques.

Please note I am not advertising either products nor have I ever used them and able to prove their authenticity as a good product. Use at your own discretion.

Comment: Seems like a good alternative as well. Too bad it's not free. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

While there currently is no Duolingo course teaching Tagalog to English speakers, [the reverse option (teaching English to Tagalog speakers) is now in the Incubator and is set for a release date at the end of May 2017](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/en/tl/status). Although that might not directly benefit you, it's a strong indication that a [reverse course teaching Tagalog to English speakers](https://incubator.duolingo.com/courses/tl/en/status) is on its way.

Comment: The current estimate for English for Tagalog Speakers is 2018-05-01. Tagalog for English has not been started yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Mango Languages](https://mangolanguages.com/) has a Tagalog program that is good-not quite as "gamified" as Duolingo but nonetheless helpful and fun. You can get a free account through a library card (at least for my area).

One downside to Mango Languages is that it has only 1 unit (10 chapters) for Tagalog.

I've used Rosetta Stone, Mango, and Duolingo before and I think Mango Languages has the best grammar explanations/education.

Answer (score 1):

Clozemaster, https://www.clozemaster.com/ , has Tagalog courses from Arabic and English, as well as Arabic and English courses from Tagalog. (More language pairs can be asked for.)

Clozemaster is not suitable at the very beginning stage; rather, it can be used after acquiring a basic level of understanding. It presents you with a sentence with one hidden word and with translation(s), and then asks you to write down the missing word or to choose it from among presented alternatives.

Learning Tagalog from another language will teach you how to write the language, some phrases, and how to read the language. Learning another language from Tagalog will teach passive understanding of text, but might be easier to start with.

Clozemaster is gamified and much slicker to use than Duolingo web interface. It also shows accents, which Duolingo neglects.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, both that Clozemaster is good overall, and that it is less suitable for total beginners.

However I want to add that if you are using it at a more elementary level, you can use the "listening" skill, and multiple choice exercises, to get started, and then phase into actually typing out answers. I find that that way, it is actually pretty accessible for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Duolingo's really fun for learning languages but too bad it does not offer Tagalog. However, there are many other alternatives. Here's a great resource with [6 alternative apps to learn Tagalog](https://heyexplorer.com/best-apps-to-learn-tagalog/).

There's Mondly, Memrise and Pimsleur. There are also these two apps: "Learn Tagalog by Dalubhasa" and "Learn Tagalog With Master Ling", if you haven't checked those out yet. You could get Rosetta Stone as an app as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to LL.SE! Could you mention if you are affiliated with the linked website or not?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely the best app to learn Tagalog is Ling App https://ling-app.com/learn-tagalog-language/

Comment: Please expand your post by adding evidence to support the "absolutely the best" claim. Take a look on how other answers do so.